# Change Name of Quartz JobDetails

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler, jobs, quartz

I have a quartz job :

```
<bean id="exportResult" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean">
  <property name="jobClass" value="com.al6.integration.quartz.JobLauncherDetails"/>
  <property name="name" value="TestJob"/>
  <property name="durability" value="false"/>
  <property name="requestsRecovery" value ="true"/>
  <property name="jobDataAsMap">
      <map>
      <entry key="jobName" value="TestJob" />
    </map>
  </property>
</bean>
```

If I launch two times in parallel this job, I had this error :

org.quartz.ObjectAlreadyExistsException: Unable to store Job...because one already exists with this identification.

So I want to update the Name of the job dynamically :

```
private JobDetail exportResult;
    
private Trigger trigger;

...

String uniqueID = "TestJob" + UUID.randomUUID().toString();
exportResult.setName(uniqueID);
trigger.setJobName(uniqueID);
scheduler.scheduleJob( exportResult, trigger);
```

It seem to work in remote debug, but when I try to compile with maven, it can't find the setName method :

```
cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method setName(java.lang.String)
[ERROR] location: variable exportResult of type org.quartz.JobDetail
cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method setJobName(java.lang.String)
[ERROR] location: variable trigger of type org.quartz.Trigger
```

It seems that the method "setName" existed before quart-scheduler version < 2.0.0 :

https://javadoc.io/doc/org.quartz-scheduler/quartz/2.0.0/org/quartz/JobDetail.html

https://javadoc.io/doc/org.quartz-scheduler/quartz/1.8.6/org/quartz/JobDetail.html

How can I change the name then ?

Answer (score 0):

Name and Group are read-only properties, as they are final fields in the JobKey property (JobDetail.getKey() --> JobKey)

I would suggest you to create the Jobs dynamically, so you can guarantee to generate unique names. The Factory pattern could be useful.